# close var XDocument.Load method/way

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

how do I close this document that was called this way:

```
var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(new XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath("Nc.xml")));
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XmlTextReader implements IDisposable. In general, you should call IDisposable.Dispose() as soon as you no longer need the resource to allow the system to close open handles, etc.

The best use pattern for IDisposable is to use the `using` syntax, which will call IDisposable.Dispose() automatically in an implicit `try..finally` wrapper:

```
using (var reader = new XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath("Nc.xml")))
{
    var xdoc = XDocument.Load(reader);
    { .. do xdoc work here .. }
} // reader disposed here
```

or if you want to keep the xdoc around a long time for other work but want to close the file as soon as possible, do it this way:

```
XDocument xdoc = null;
using (var reader = new XmlTextReader(Server.MapPath("Nc.xml")))
{
    xdoc = XDocument.Load(reader);
} // reader disposed here

{ .. do xdoc work here .. }
```

Answer (score 1):

Once the reader is done, it will close the what it has read automatically.

otherwise hang the reference out for GC by

```
xmlDoc = null;
```

which will tear down any internal open items.